# Get country for a given ccTLD

Tags: python

Assuming I have a tld extracted as:

```
ext = tldextract.extract(item.get("google.co.uk"))
print(magic_func(ext.suffix)) > United Kingdoms
```

How can I achieve this `magic_func` functionality without querying DBPedia/Wikipedia etc.? I am only interested in country tlds.

Edit: Querying the web is quite costly for me as I may have millions of cctlds to check!

Comment: But TLDs don't necessarily map to a country.

Comment: Querying the web isn't costly if you pull down the whole database and cache it locally.

Comment: @PeterWood Exactly, for a quantitative project, I need to find what percent do map! I am getting the geo-location using the standard query.

Comment: @abarnert I guess that's the last retort, I was hoping for ready-made dict of country and cctld, like https://gist.github.com/carlopires/1261951

Comment: That's still pulling it down off the internet, just manually, and much earlier (as part of the dev process and/or as part of installing requirements), so more chance for it to be stale.